# The ways to include another classes in a class file

Tags: c++

I am learning c++ and confused about the ways to include another class in current class. For example, I am wondering whether `class QuackBehavior` equals to `#include <QuackBehavior.h>`. If they are equal, what are the differences between these two ways? The code is :

```
#include <string>

class QuackBehavior;

class Duck {
public:
    Duck();
    virtual ~Duck() {};

    virtual void performQuack();

    virtual std::string getDescription() = 0;

    std::string getName() {return m_name;}
    void setName(std::string name ) {m_name = name;}
    void setQuackBehavior(QuackBehavior * behavior);

protected:
    std::string m_name;
    QuackBehavior * m_quackBehavior;

};
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: The `class QuackBehavior;` line is a forward declaration — 'there exists a class called `QuackBehavior`'.  It is sufficient to let a client of `class Duck` compile without including `<QuackBehavior.h>` — which speeds up compilation.  It won't be enough for implementing the quack behaviour, though.

Comment: This may help you understand forward declarations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/c-forward-declaration

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That makes sense. Thank you so much.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Hey Ninja, your link is really helpful, thank you so much!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am wondering does the compiler will go to look for the `QuackBehavior.h` file or not if I just write `class QuackBehavior`. Thank you

Comment: If you don't say `#include "QuackBehavior.h"` or `#include <QuackBehavior.h>`, the compiler won't go looking to include the file.  For all it knows, the details are in `Queen-of-Sheba.h` anyway.  The header name being the class name plus `.h` is merely conventional.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I see, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two are not equal:

`class QuackBehavior;` is considered a forward-declaration, and simply informs the compiler that there is a `class` called `QuackBehavior`. This can only be used if you are using `QuackBehavior` as a pointer or reference:

```
class B;
struct C;
struct A
{
    shared_ptr<B> getB() const { return b; }
    const C& getC() const;
private:
    shared_ptr<B> b;
};
```

Here the compiler doesn't need to know any implementation details of `C` and `B`, only that they exist. Notice that it's important to tell the compiler whether it's a `class` or `struct` also.

`#include <QuackBehavior>` is an include, and essentially copies+pastes the entire file into your file. This allows the compiler and linker to see everything about `QuackBehavior`. Doing this is slower, as you'll then include everything that `QuackBehavior` includes, and everything those files include. This can increase compile times dramatically.

Both are different, and both have their places:

- Use forward-declaration when you don't need to know the implementation details of a class just yet, only that they exist (e.g. use in pointers and references)
- Include the file if you are declaring an object, or you need to use functions or members of a class.

Answer (score 1):

In QuackBehavior.h file, forwarding declaring QuackBehavior class will suffice.

```
#include <string>

class QuackBehavior; // tells the compiler that a class called QuackBehavior exists without any further elaborations

class Duck {
 public:
   Duck();
   virtual ~Duck() {};

   virtual void performQuack();

   virtual std::string getDescription() = 0;

   std::string getName() {return m_name;}
   void setName(std::string name ) {m_name = name;}
   void setQuackBehavior(QuackBehavior * behavior);

  protected:
   std::string m_name;
   QuackBehavior * m_quackBehavior;
};
```

However in QuackBehavior.cpp file, you have to use #include"QuackBehavior.h" so that the compiler can find the implementation member functions

```
#include <QuackBehavior.h> 
#include <string>
duck::duck()
{
}
```